# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission needed to open content://media/external/[...] in MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, permissions, android-mediaplayer, android-contentprovider, android-external-storage

I'm playing an alarm sound in my App. On most devices this works flawlessly. Some users have described that no sound is playing. This seems to mainly affect Samsung and Huawei devices. This is a minimal example of where things fail:

```
alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
try {
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alarmUri);   
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(audioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {                
                Log.d(logtag,"Exception: " + e);
        }
```

For affected users, the following exception is thrown:

> Exception java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.:
>   status=0x80000000

This only seems to happen when alarmURI looks like this: `content://media/external/audio/media/11`, i.e. it resides on an external store. I have never seen it occur when alarmURI looks this this `content://media/internal/audio/media/40`.

Do I need the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in order to play the sound, if the Uri I use contains the `/external/` part? Or am I missing something else? Normally, I would  expect a SecurityException to be thrown, if the permission was the issue.

/e: I could reproduce the bug on my device. Here is a more detailed error report:

> Exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/audio/media from pid=27158, uid=10177
>   requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Normally, I would expect a SecurityException

You don't get SecurityException, because you code fails upon hitting Linux filesystem (OS-level) permissions, not Android framework permissions. There are no strict guarantees about `RuntimeException`s you receive from API (such as SecurityException), this is why they are called "unchecked Exceptions" in the first place.

> Do I need the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in order to play the sound, if the Uri I use contains the `/external/` part?

Never use contents of externally-provided Uri to make any decisions in your code. Just treat them as opaque strings.

> This only seems to happen when alarmURI looks like this…, i.e. it resides on an external store. I have never seen it occur when alarmURI looks this this…

You are correct in posting the Uris for troubleshooting, but it is also helpful to know, where the Uri comes from. Modern versions of Android use [dynamic Uri permission model](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Intents). That is: your level of access to Uri may differ, depending on where Uri came from and whether the caller has added [FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) to Intent (or called `Context#grantUriPermission` for the same result), and whether you have called `Context#takePersistableUriPermission` upon receiving the Intent with Uri.

Yes, you might need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Android uses FUSE or similar vendor-specific API to adjust visible OS-level permissions of external storage depending on permission of calling application: when your app has the permission, external files look readable to it (File#isReadable returns *true*), when it does not, external files look inaccessible to it (File#isReadable returns *false*). Of course, that should only be relevant for files, but what if the caller gives you a `file://` Uri? Also the ContentProvider behind the Uri may check if you have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission before giving you the file descriptor (it's silly, but certainly possible).

In addition, it is a good idea to open the Uri yourself and supply the stream/file descriptor to the the player instead of Uri. Most Linux security checks<sup>*</sup> happen when you open a file descriptor. In order to achieve predictable behavior, you should open the Uri in your own code and do as much error handling as possible, including catching RuntimeException from remote ContentProvider.

Why does the issue arise? There could be multiple reasons, but it is probably one of these:

1. The MediaStorage ContentProvider on guilty devices is simply buggy (manufacturers can and often do replace system ContentProviders with custom buggy versions)
2. The MediaPlayer implementation on guilty devices is buggy
3. The SELinux permissions on guilty devices are flawed (restrict the access to files too much)
4. Your code receives Uris, stores them somewhere, but does not call `takePersistableUriPermission`, so your access is invalidated after app restart.

It is hard to diagnose the exact issue without Exception stack trace. Either way, if suggestions above don't help, there is little you could do aside from using different API for playing sound files and/or forcing user to pick alarm sound without using Android MediaProvider.

---

<sup>*</sup> *except some SELinux checks, but you can't really do anything about those*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was really insightful. I have started to read up on all topics that you mentioned. Also, I successfully reproduced the error and was also able to resolve it. Requesting the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission solves it. However, I would like to use as few permissions as possible. Hence, I tried looking up how to implement the dynamic uri permissions, but I was not able to figure it out. There are two ways to receive the uri:

Comment: 1. RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri() and 2. Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
The docs of RingtoneManager don't mention dynamic permissions. So I really don't now how to get started...

Comment: @mc51 No docs explicitly mention dynamic permissions (aside from docs of relevant methods themselves), because dynamic permissions didn't exist when ContentProvider system has been created. They were introduced in later versions of Android. When you use picker Intent, call `takePersistableUriPermission` after receiving a Uri. Not sure, how to deal with `getActualDefaultRingtoneUri`, you might want to look, how various open source apps use it.

Comment: 1/2 @mc51 note, that actual degree of support for dynamic permission depends on specific ContentProvider and how you receive the Uri. Some system APIs simply don't play well with dynamic permissions and some ContentProviders won't grant you the permission at all. For instance, Uri from clipboard will not magically become available to you (because the process, that placed it there, did not know, who would receive it). So Uris stored in Android clipboard have to come from public ContentProviders prior to Android O. It is possible, that in your case there is similarly no support at all…

Comment: 2/2 @mc51 …and declaring a permission is the only workaround, available to you.

Comment: As a note, I do get a `Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media/1699 from pid=16477, uid=10104 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()`. The quality and depth of this answer is outstanding, rarely seen on SO.